# GetTokenInformation with ctypes

Tags: python, winapi, token, ctypes

I'm trying to use the GetTokenInformation function with ctypes.
The problem is that it will always print None.

```
import winappdbg
from ctypes import *

LPVOID = c_void_p
PVOID = LPVOID
PSID = PVOID
DWORD = c_uint32


class SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Sid",         PSID),
        ("Attributes",  DWORD),
    ]

class TOKEN_USER(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("User", SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES),]

tokenprivs = (winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_QUERY | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_READ | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_DUPLICATE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY)
hProcess = winappdbg.win32.OpenProcess(winappdbg.win32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, winappdbg.win32.GetCurrentProcessId())
hToken = winappdbg.win32.OpenProcessToken(hProcess, DesiredAccess = tokenprivs)

tokeninformation = TOKEN_USER()
dwLength = DWORD(0)
windll.advapi32.GetTokenInformation(hToken, winappdbg.win32.TokenUser, byref(tokeninformation), sizeof(TOKEN_USER), byref(dwLength))
print tokeninformation.User.Sid
```

P.S. I'm aware that win32security.GetTokenInformation exists. But I want to use ctypes because of the real process handlers.

EDIT:

Working code:

```
import winappdbg
from ctypes import *

LPVOID = c_void_p
PVOID = LPVOID
PSID = PVOID
DWORD = c_uint32

class SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Sid",         PSID),
        ("Attributes",  DWORD),
    ]

class TOKEN_USER(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("User", SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES),]

tokenprivs = (winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_QUERY | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_READ | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_DUPLICATE | winappdbg.win32.TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY)
hProcess = winappdbg.win32.OpenProcess(winappdbg.win32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, winappdbg.win32.GetCurrentProcessId())
hToken = winappdbg.win32.OpenProcessToken(hProcess, DesiredAccess = tokenprivs)

dwSize = DWORD(0)
pStringSid = winappdbg.win32.LPSTR()

windll.advapi32.GetTokenInformation(hToken, winappdbg.win32.TokenUser, None, 0, byref(dwSize))

address = windll.kernel32.LocalAlloc(0x0040, dwSize)
print "Address: " + str(address)

windll.advapi32.GetTokenInformation(hToken, winappdbg.win32.TokenUser, address, dwSize, byref(dwSize))
print FormatError(GetLastError())

pToken_User = cast(address, POINTER(TOKEN_USER))

windll.advapi32.ConvertSidToStringSidA(pToken_User.contents.User.Sid, byref(pStringSid))
print "SID: " + pStringSid.value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a query for the token information class `TokenUser` stores a `TOKEN_USER` structure in the target buffer, it does not contain all the required information by itself. As you can see in the structure's documentation, it contains just the `SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` structure, which in turn contains only a *pointer* to a SID and an integer with flags.

If you added some more error checking, you would see that your call to `GetTokenInformation()` does not succeed, the reported error code is `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (122) and `dwLength` is set to something like 36 (definitely more than `sizeof(TOKEN_USER)`, which is just 8).

Apparently the function wants enough space in the target buffer to store even the SID itself, then point to that extra data from the documented output structure `TOKEN_USER`.

---

I don't know Ctypes much, but you will need to create the output buffer as a real buffer/array instead of just the structure, and perform some casting on it to get the data. You can either take the easy way and create the buffer large enough on the first try, or call the function twice, first to get the required buffer length, second to fill it.